# Maximum absolute difference of value and index sums of Four arrays

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, difference, absolute

You are given four arrays A, B, C, D each of size N.
Find maximum value (M) of given below expression

```
M = max(|A[i] - A[j]| + |B[i] - B[j]| + |C[i] - C[j]| + |D[i] - D[j]| + |i -j|)
Where 1 <= i < j  <= N <br />
```

and here |**x**| refers to the absolute value of x.

Constraints

```
2 <= N <= 10^5  
1 <= Ai,Bi,Ci,Di <= 10^9
```

- Input: N,A,B,C,D
- Output: M

Ex.-

```
Input-   
5  
5,7,6,3,9  
7,9,2,7,5  
1,9,9,3,3  
8,4,1,10,5
```

Output-

```
24
```

[Question picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYPpu.jpg)

I have tried this way

```
def max_value(arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4, n): 
    res = 0; 
    # Iterating two for loop,  
    # one for i and another for j. 
    for i in range(n): 
        for j in range(n):  
            temp= abs(arr1[i] - arr1[j]) + abs(arr2[i] - arr2[j]) + abs(arr3[i] - arr3[j]) + abs(arr4[i] - arr4[j]) + abs(i - j)
            if res>temp:
                res = res
            else:
                res = temp
    return res;
```

This is O(n^2).
But I want a better time complexity solution. This will not work for higher values of N.

[Here is solution for single array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-value-arri-arrj-j)

Comment: In your code i goes from 1 to n and j goes from 1 to n, but in the first statement you say that i is always smaller than j. I guess both go to n?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can generalize the solution for a single array that you showed. Given a number `K` of arrays, including the array of indices, one can make `2**K` possible combinations of arrays to get rid of the absolute values. It is then easy to just take the max and min of each of these combinations separately and compare them. This is order O(Kn*2^K), much better than the original O(Kn^2) for the values you report.

Here is a code that works on an arbitrary number of input arrays.

```
import numpy as np

def run(n, *args):
    aux = np.arange(n)

    K = len(args) + 1
    rows = 2 ** K
    x = np.zeros((rows, n))
    for i in range(rows):
        temp = 0
        for m, a in enumerate(args):
            temp += np.array(a) * ((-1) ** int(f"{i:0{K}b}"[-(1+m)]))
        temp += aux * ((-1) ** int(f"{i:0{K}b}"[-K]))
        x[i] = temp

    x_max = np.max(x, axis=-1)
    x_min = np.min(x, axis=-1)
    res = np.max(x_max - x_min)
    return res
```

The `for` loop maybe deserves more explanation: in order to make all possible combinations of absolute values, I assign each combination to an integer and rely on the binary representation of this integer to choose which ones of the K vectors must be taken negative.

Comment: Not sure if you've got an off-by-one error but `run(5, (5,7,6,3,9), (7,9,2,7,5), (1,9,9,3,3), (8,4,1,10,5))` gives `24`, instead of 25. (Or the question has the wrong expected output.)

Comment: Using the OP's code, the answer is also `24` for values `i=2`, `j=3`. I think it's a typo in the question.

Comment: Yeah, that is 24, not 25. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Idea for faster solution

- If you are only interested in the maximum of M you could search for the minimum and maximum value of A, B,C, D and i-j.Let's say i_Amax is the i index for the maximum of A.
- Now you find the value of B[i_Amax], C[i_Amax].... and the same for i_Amin and calculate M with the differences of the max and min value.
- You repeated the step before with the index for the maximum value of B, so i_Bmax and calculate M, you repeat until you gone through A,B,C,D and i-j
- You now should have five terms and one of them should be the maximum

If you don't have a clear minimum or maximum you have to calculate the indeces for all the possible minimums and maximums.

I think it should find any maximum and is faster than n^2, especially for big n, but I have not implemented it myself, so you have to think it through to check whether I made a logical error and one can not find every maximum with that idea.

I hope that helps!